# can't get current time

Tags: android, time

I need the current time in milliseconds, so I use Calendar object to retrieve hours and minutes and convert them into milliseconds, but everytime it returns same value, that's the problem.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int milliseconds = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)*60*60*1000 + 
calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Callendar.getTimeInMillis() and System doesn't work for me cause I can't convert them to daytime. What I need is current daytime but in milliseconds.

Comment: You can use java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis() to get time in millis directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#getTime()

(new Date()).getTime())

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

System.currentTimeMillis());

Both these methods returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that it counts time from 1970, thank you, now its clear to me.

Answer (score 4):

use this

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: I need current day time in milliseconds, how can I convert the value from System.currentTimeMillis() to current daytime in milliseconds?

Comment: current day time in milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis()
```

to get time in millis directly for that particular Calendar instance. If you just need Current time use

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Comment: For example 6:24 am is 1500359038901, how can I retrieve daytime in milliseconds from the value from Calendar.getTimeInMillis()?

Comment: So do you need time in milliseconds for a particular date and time right?

Comment: 6:24 am today can be 1500359038901 but 6:24 am tomorrow will have a different value

Comment: try to convert 1500359038901 to hours

Comment: 416766,3996947222 hours

Comment: I am sorry i am now confused. Can you tell me what is the exact requirement so that i can understand it better.

Comment: @KarlssonMakhno what's your exact requirement ??

Comment: What I need is current daytime but in milliseconds.

Comment: Current daytime you can get through System.currentTimeMillis() this time is always with reference to 1st Jan 1970. so the number of milliseconds that have gone by from that date.

Answer (score 1):

try this use  [currentTimeMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) it will Returns the current time in milliseconds.

```
Long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
Log.i("Time Class ", " Time value in millisecinds "+time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read **[currentTimeMillis](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis())**.

> Returns the current time in milliseconds. Note that while the unit of
>   time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the
>   value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger.

```
long getTIME= calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```